# 抱った vs 抱いた and 書った vs 書いた

Tags: conjugations

I have always known that for a verb that ends with a `く`, the past/perfective form ends with `いた` and the conjugative form ends with `いて`.

But today I found in Wiktionary that there are alternative perfective forms [`抱った`/`抱って` for `抱く`](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%8A%B1%E3%81%8F#Conjugation_2) and [`書った`/`書って` for `書く`](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8F#Related_terms).

Are those simply typo/mistake in Wiktionary or could there be some truths in them?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Looks like someone already fixed 抱った to 抱いた in the page for 抱く but it is still for 書った in the page for 書く.

Comment: 抱った, 抱って, 書った, and 書って are all incorrect.

Comment: “I have always known that for a verb that ends with a く, the past/perfective form ends with いた and the conjugative form ends with いて.”  There is at least one exception to that rule.  Can you name it?  This was my favorite quiz as a junior high school student (you know how nerdy I was).  I do not remember whether I came up with this quiz by myself or I heard it from someone else.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto 行く. 行った. 行って. I didn't notice it until you asked :P

Comment: Lukman: Right! :)

Answer (score 2):

I no longer use Rikaichan because it made me lazy (and I switched to Chrome...), but I remember that if you typed a く verb with a って/った　conjugation and punched it in, it would still pop up and show as the て/た　form. Give it a shot. Unfortunately I can't explain why, but it leads me to believe that maybe it was correct at some point. There's a 国語 teacher right next to me, but I'm too embarrassed to ask :/